# Disable fixed button position

Tags: css

I am editing a design that comes with social media buttons that follow you as you scroll up and down the page.  I would like that behavior to stop so they are only visible when you're at the top.  I think this is the relevant code (not 100% sure):

```
.rt-social-buttons .rt-social-icon {
   height: 43px;
   width: 43px;
   float: right;
   display: block;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin-bottom: 2px;
   -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in, background-color 0.2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in, background-color 0.2s ease-in;
   -o-transition: width 0.2s ease-in, background-color 0.2s ease-in;
   -ms-transition: width 0.2s ease-in, background-color 0.2s ease-in;
   transition: width 0.2s ease-in, background-color 0.2s ease-in;
 }

.rt-social-buttons .rt-social-icon:hover {
   width: 150px;
 }
```

And the site is [here](http://shoutkey.com/spicy).

What do I need to remove from the code above to stop the buttons from moving?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the buttons are stuck with the page as it scrolls is the `position: fixed` on the `.rt-social-buttons` div.

Here's what I did to make them static on the right:

1.) The div `.rt-social-buttons` gets `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed`

2.) The div `.rt-social-buttons` gets pulled out into the body (the `.container` div is relatively positioned, so absolutely positioning the `.rt-social-buttons` div inside will not allow it to be positioned at the same place.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understand step 2.  What exactly do I need to do there?

Comment: @KnocksX You need to move the div itself outside into the body, it's currently inside `.rt-container > #rt-transition`.

Comment: But it's not a div, those icons are sitting in their own html file.